# Design for a special WCF service

Tags: wcf

I need to implement a WCF service which in turn calls a third party web service for some XML result.The client calls come from windows WF apps & will be on separate processes.But for client calls coming from the same parentID, there should be only one call per ParentID, i will explain,

MainID1\SubID1 & MainID1\SubID1 on different processes calls the WCF service for result & if MainID1\SubID1 was the first to make the call,  MainID1\SubID2 should wait until the first call is completed.The idea is to prevent unnecessary call to the third party web service, if we get the expected results already from the first call.

But if there are MainID2\SubID1,MainID2\SubID2,MainID2\SubID3 calls, that should be served by a different instance of the WCF service.

In short:

1. Related requests should be processed sequentially by one instance of WCF  service
2. Unrelated requests should be processed by separate instance

Sorry, if haven't made myself clear, not at the liberty to use the actual business terms(which might have helped to define related & unrelated clients better).

Is this really possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but it will not be trivial.  Basically you need another component between your WCF Web Service and the 3rd Party service which handles the throttling/locking behavior which you describe.  That component needs to create a object for each unique combination and then use that as a lock guard around the outbound call.

Realize that this is clearly multi-threaded development, making it hard to test, and prone to errors if you're not experienced with the ideas around it.  You'll want to ensure you're doing double-checked locking whenever you take out a lock.

Comment: Based on my limited knowledge of WCF, i am having a feeling that, this WCF need to be a "Single Instance,Multiple Concurrency" with locking, so each call can be on seperate thread, so far fine.But a Single Instance is not what am looking for.There should be multiple instances serving unrelated requests.But i cannot find a way to achieve that, can you direct me to any sample codes or pointers?, Thanks already!